# How to create a screen dialog

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a screen with a form, in some situations, I want to show a popup style menu. How could I do so without affecting the layout of the form that is behind the popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the `InputPrompt` from the [Coding4Fun Toolkit for Windows Phone 7](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). You can get details on how to do this in [this blog post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-CustomInputPrompt-control-with-Cancel-button)

Answer (score 0):

A good choice as well is the Telerik option:

[Telerik Windows Phone 7 - Window Control](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/window.aspx)